# Java - Converting bytes in to string and comparing against another

Tags: java, string, compare, byte

I'm just starting to learn Java, and for my first challenge I am trying to read the ID3v1 tag from an MP3. I read the last 128 bytes of an MP3 in to a byte array and split it up from there. To check I have found a valid ID3 tag I convert the first 3 bytes from the array in to a string and compare it to "TAG". The problem is the string made up from the bytes never matches the "TAG" string, even though it looks like it should when I run it in the eclipse debugger.

I've pasted the code I'm using below, Can anyone please point out what it is I am doing wrong here?

```
byte tagBytes[] = {84, 65, 71}; //Normally filed from a file, just here as an example.
String tagHeader = null; //String to hold tag header
tagHeader = Character.toString((char)tagBytes[0]) + 
            Character.toString((char)tagBytes[1]) + 
            Character.toString((char)tagBytes[2]);
if (tagHeader != "TAG"){
    System.out.println("No ID3v1 tag found");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: [How to compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+string+compare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings cannot be compared by `==` as this checks if the literal references in memory are the same.  Instead do `"TAG".equals(tagHeader)` or `"TAG".equalsIgnoreCase(tagHeader)` to do a case-insensitive comparison.

You can also simplify your string building, like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    sb.append((char)tagBytes[i]);
}
tagHeader = sb.toString();
```

Or even, as @Vulcan suggest, simply:

```
tagHeader = new String(tagBytes,0,3);
```

You'll likely want to specify the charset as well, otherwise the bytes may be converted incorrectly.  Depending on how your data's encoded, you may want to specify a different charset:

```
tagHeader = new String(tagBytes,0,3,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Or even `tagHeader = new String(tagBytes)`.

Comment: Good call, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This will turn bytes into a String and properly:

```
byte tagBytes[] = {84, 65, 71}; 
String s = new String(tagBytes, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

Your solution also works.  It's your comparison that is the problem.  You want:

```
if (!tagHeader.equals("TAG")) {
```

In the case of a String, `!=` or `==` test that the two String are the same instance, not the same value.  You need to use the `equals()` method to compare them by value.

Variants:
To select just a portion of the byte array:

```
String s = new String(tagBytes, 0, 3, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

If the entire byte array has been converted to a string, and you want to see if it does not start with "TAG":

```
if (!tagHeader.startsWith("TAG")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the bytes to a `String` if you are sure that they are all ASCII (or if you know the encoding). Then you should compare with `equals` not `!=` since the later checks if it is not the same instance. In your case it is always a different instance.

```
    byte tagBytes[] = {84, 65, 71};
    String tagHeader = new String(tagBytes, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    if (!"TAG".equals(tagHeader)){
        System.out.println("No ID3v1 tag found");
        return null;
    }
```

Or you can avoid creating redundant `String` objects altogether by just doing this:

```
    byte tagBytes[] = {84, 65, 71};
    if (!('T' == tagBytes[0] && 'A' == tagBytes[1] && 'G' == tagBytes[2])){
        System.out.println("No ID3v1 tag found");
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in simple way you can do as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte tagBytes[] = {84, 65, 71}; //Normally filed from a file, just here fro example.
    String tagHeader = null; //String to hold tag header
    tagHeader = new String(tagBytes);
    if (!tagHeader.equals("TAG")){
        System.out.println("No ID3v1 tag found");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `tagHeader != "TAG"` to `!tagHeader.equals("TAG")`

Currently, you are comparing memory addresses and not the actual values.

I wrote it this way for clarity. For null safe code, you should always use the literal first.

i.e.

```
"TAG".equals(tagHeader)
```